# CSS3 Layout - 4 column with Polygin

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem with 4 columns layout inside my view.

I must build this layout:

[image: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2ntz6gg.jpg]

Anybody know how I can make this layout? I use `-clip` method but first `div` always is another from last `div`. Two centered div is OK but first and last not.

Please, help me if you know how I can do this...

Comment: Please post the html & css you have tried so far.

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote/accept if my answer was helpful to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using trapezoid borders in combination with positioning:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.section {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 300px solid #346;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.s1 .background {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  z-index: 5;
}
.s2 .background {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  z-index: 4;
}
.s3 .background {
  border-bottom-color: navy;
  z-index: 3;
}
.s4 .background {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section s1">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="section s2">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="section s3">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="section s4 last">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**Limits**: You have to define a fixed height (`300px` in the example above)